# Loop through array not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm using google charts to generate charts, where I want to use array data. It works fine when I use the array variable with index. But when I am looping through the array, only the last index value of the array is shown.

```
   for(var i=0;i<myTableArray.length;i++)
   {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2013',  1000,      400],
      ['2014',  1170,      460],
      ['2015',  660,       1120],
      ['2016',  1030,      540],
      ['2019',1233,122],
      myTableArray[0],  //works 
      myTableArray[1], //works
      myTableArray[i]   // value of myTableArray[1] is shown
      ]);
      alert(myTableArray[i]);
   }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: What is the length of your `myTableArray` array?

Comment: length of the array is 2

Comment: What’s in `myTableArray`?

Comment: myTableArray=["xyxy","1212","21212"];

Comment: myTableArray is a collection table data

Comment: mofidul,

 try this way
     [ myTableArray[0],  
       myTableArray[1],
       myTableArray[i] ]

Comment: Baloch it only showing the  myTableArray[0] value